# How do I save variables and load them in Unity with JavaScript?

Tags: unity, javascript, savegame

I made a game and i want to save the high score and load it back. I need to save 3 variables and load them when the game starts. How do i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) class. It's a key/value system that allows you to save, or read, a value.

Comment: Just a quick word of caution: PlayerPrefs saves values into the Registry on Windows.